# How to groupby by _id in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, group-by, aggregate, mern

For VendorItem collection, I want to have my items grouped by(like SQL) in category but using group in mongo there are no accumulator for _id! Help me Thaks in advance.
param -> vendor's id

 **Output :** [category_id1 : [ it's items ], category_id2: [it's items]]

**Model**

```
let vendorItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    category: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        required: true, 
        ref:'VendorCategory' 
    },
    vendor : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: Vendor
    },
    item: {type: String, required: true}, 
    price: {type: Number, required: true}, 
    inStock: {type: Boolean, required: true}, 
    //order:{} 
});  
vendorItemSchema.index({category: 1}); 

const VendorItem = mongoose.model('VendorItem',vendorItemSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- probably with group by `_id` you mean to collect all the document info so you need maybe the `$$ROOT`
- the bellow has 3 accumulators, keep only the ones you need
- sum quantity, collect items(strings) , collect the root documents

*if this isn't what you need if you can give sample data in json, and the expected output

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":
  {"_id":"$category",
   "count":{"$sum":1},
   "items":{"$push":"$item"},
   "docs":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the equivalent of the following SQL instruction:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table
GROUP BY your_field
HAVING COUNT(*) > N

```
**query = db.collection.aggregate([

    { 
      "$group": { "_id": "$your_field", #GROUP BY your_field
                "count": {"$sum":1} }   #COUNT(*)
    },
    
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": N } } } #HAVING COUNT(*) > N
])**
```

Comment: It gave me count I want all items of that _id```"items": [
        {
            "_id": "621c6d874d6d79e83219e5ae",
            "count": 4
        },
        {
            "_id": "621c6dde4d6d79e83219e5b8",
            "count": 2
        }
    ],```